# How install a new app from LiveCD into sleeping hard drive installation

Tags: installation, hard-drive, live-cd

I've:

- a pc with a running Ubuntu installation.
- a LiveCD running in the above pc with access to the hard drive Ubuntu installation filesystem.

and I need to know how install an app from the running LiveCD to the Ubuntu installation, so when I boot the hard drive installed Ubuntu that app is correctly installed & available.

Thanks

Comment: What is the App?

Comment: @Mitch: festival, a text-to-speech synthetiser but now I'm curious if I can install any other app.

Comment: Yes, you can, first chroot to drive in which ubuntu is installed, then simply type sudo apt-get install packegane name

Answer (score 0):

1. Chroot to the drive containing existing ubuntu installation

2 . `sudo apt-get install <package name>`